# After upgrading to ionic3 - Gradle sync failed: No match found

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, ionic3

I upgraded the project to ionic 3 (from ionic 2). the project runs well on the browser by using:

```
ionic serve
```

I removed the android platform and added it again. Then I want to test it on an android phone so I run the following:

```
ionic build --release android
```

Then I open the project on android studio and I get the following error:

```
Gradle sync failed: No match found
```

I already upgraded gradle and android studio and I am stuck with this problem.

This is the config.xml on ionic project:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="2.9.1" id="com.plato.app" ios-CFBundleVersion="2.9.1" version="2.9.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>PlatoWork</name>
    <description>Nerostimulation for work</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.176:8100" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file parent="NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>PlatoIonic would like to use bluetooth.</string>
        </config-file>
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <resource-file src="resources/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist" target="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="wp8">
        <icon height="99" src="resources\wp8\icon\ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
        <icon height="159" src="resources\wp8\icon\Background.png" width="159" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="70000" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.3.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ble-central" spec="^1.1.4">
        <variable name="BLUETOOTH_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="the bluetooth connection is used to connect with the physical device called PlatoWork headset - arduino" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-rfduino" spec="^0.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-deploy" spec="^0.6.7" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-open-native-settings" spec="^1.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativestorage" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="^1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics" spec="^0.11.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="~0.1.9" />
</widget>
```

This is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "plato-work",
  "author": "ric",
  "homepage": "http://www.testwqr.com",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.1",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-analytics": "4.3.1",
    "@ionic-native/open-native-settings": "4.3.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.0",
    "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.0",
    "cordova-open-native-settings": "^1.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "~0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-ble-central": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^0.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-rfduino": "^0.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.1",
    "ionic": "^3.18.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionic-plugin-deploy": "^0.6.7",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-rfduino",
    "cordova-plugin-ble-central",
    "cordova-plugin-compat",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "PlatoIonic: An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-ble-central": {
        "BLUETOOTH_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "the bluetooth connection is used to connect with the physical device called PlatoWork headset - arduino"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-rfduino": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-deploy": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-open-native-settings": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the log:

```
   2017-11-17 11:54:22,968 [thread 141]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - No match found

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2017-11-17 11:54:22,968 [thread 141]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: No match found

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (269ms) 
2017-11-17 11:54:23,069 [thread 152]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-11-17 11:54:23,070 [thread 152]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-11-17 11:54:23,070 [thread 152]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-11-17 11:54:23,071 [thread 152]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-11-17 11:54:24,995 [se-915-b08]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'android'. 
2017-11-17 11:54:25,004 [thread 152]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home 
2017-11-17 11:54:25,005 [thread 152]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home 
2017-11-17 11:54:25,008 [thread 152]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.local.repo contents "allprojects {\n  buildscript {\n    repositories {\n      maven { url '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository'}\n    }\n  }\n  repositories {\n      maven { url '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository'}\n  }\n}\n" 
2017-11-17 11:54:25,009 [thread 152]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.version=3.0 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.0.0.18 --init-script /private/var/folders/ks/4836vv0s3d3bnqbxxw929zx00000gn/T/sync.local.repo716.gradle --init-script /private/var/folders/ks/4836vv0s3d3bnqbxxw929zx00000gn/T/ijinit.gradle 
2017-11-17 11:54:25,215 [thread 152]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:258)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:902)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Script '/Users/ricardoparro/Plato/PlatoIonic/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 128
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:135)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at
```

cordova requirements command output:
Requirements check results for android:

```
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-27,android-26
Gradle: installed /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed [object Object]
ios-deploy: installed [object Object]
CocoaPods: installed [object Object]
```

**Note:** I was able to run the app on xcode and ios.

Comment: try running `cordova requirements` in your project folder

Comment: @SurajRao added it to the description. I am still having problems. let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some weird reason on the config file the android-versionCode can't be

```
android-versionCode="2.9.1"
```

The version code does not allow the '.' character.... that alone was creating the problem.

The solution was to put a number without the '.' character:

```
android-versionCode="291"
```